# I keep getting this error: Couldn't open "File"

Tags: pygame, error-code

I'm trying to display an image using pygame, but I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "H:/profile/desktop/untitled/venv/Scripts/AhjaiyGame.py", line 28, in 
>       start = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(folder, "wecvguh.png"))
>   pygame.error: Couldn't open H:\profile\desktop\untitled\venv\Scripts\wecvguh.png

**Code block:**

```
import sys
import random
import os
import subprocess
import pygame
pygame.init()
GUI = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("The incredible guessing game")
x = 284
y = 250
width = 68
length = 250
run = True
while run:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run =False
 if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
  command = "python AhjaiyCPT.py"
  subprocess.call(command)


 pygame.display.update()


folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

start = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(folder, "wecvguh.png"))
   def img(x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(start, (x,y))
    while run:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        start(x, y)


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Can you verify your wecvguh.png exists on the filesystem at: H:\profile\desktop\untitled\venv\Scripts\wecvguh.png ? Can you also look at the permissions granted to this image?

Comment: I fixed the error by moving the image, but the image does not display

Answer (score 1):

The code has two "run" loops, so it never gets to the second loop.

The code's indentation is confused - maybe from a paste into SO?.  The overwhelming majority of programmers use 4 spaces to indent.  This is probably a good custom to follow.

The code also loaded the "start" image every loop iteration, this is unnecessary (unless it changes on disk, in this case use `os.stat()` to check for changes before re-loading it).

Re-worked main loop:

```
folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
start  = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(folder, "wecvguh.png"))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            command = "python AhjaiyCPT.py"
            subprocess.call(command)

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    gameDisplay.blit(start, (x,y))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```